# iOS Table View word wrap overlap

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, word-wrap

I am using JSON to parse to a table view. I am using a title and a subtitle. I dont want the text to go off the screen with "..." so i added

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

I can see that it goes onto a new line but the height of the cell stays the same and overlaps other ones and looks really bad. How can i make it so it word wraps and the height expands the the amount of content in it?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer to first answer: i put in the code of UITableViewDelegate method and i get this:

```
2013-08-27 15:29:40.940 jsonParse[2392:c07] -[__NSCFDictionary 

sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7580130
2013-08-27 15:29:40.942 jsonParse[2392:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7580130'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c93012 0x10d0e7e 0x1d1e4bd 0x1c82bbc 0x1c8294e 0x333a 0x1f9c4e 0x1fc224 0xc0952 0xc02dc 0x2927 0xbd6589 0xbd4652 0xbd589a 0xbd460d 0xbd4785 0xb21a68 0x4615911 0x4614bb3 0x4652cda 0x1c358fd 0x465335c 0x46532d5 0x453d250 0x1c16f3f 0x1c1696f 0x1c39734 0x1c38f44 0x1c38e1b 0x1bed7e3 0x1bed668 0x14ffc 0x1dad 0x1cd5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: have you solved your problem, if no let me know...just seen your screenshot and found the problem

Answer (score 1):

Implement this UITableViewDelegate method for finding height of each row at run time and change the code accordingly

```
    NSString *object = [DataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = [object sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];//set the textLable Frame width according to your layout width.
    CGFloat height = size.height+20;//you can set the padding accordingly
    return height;
}
```

**Edited for specific answer**

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *title = [[articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *desc = [[articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"desc"];

    CGSize titleSize = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 99999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGSize descSize = [title sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300, 99999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return titleSize.height+descSize.height+10;
}
```

Comment: you have pass the dictionary object in NSString object. You have get the NSString object that you are setting in textLabel.text

Comment: also paste the code of -(UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath of this method

Comment: Got rid of the errors but it still looks the same, am i ment to call this method?

Comment: no, it will call automatically by property of tableview delegation. make sure you corretly setted you tableview.gelegate = self;

Comment: where do i put tableView.delegate = self?

Comment: put in viewDidLoad method and replace tableView with your instance name of UITableView object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36337/discussion-between-drdebug-and-parser)